# Isomophisms of modules

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

I'm reading a book about homological algebra. There is one exercise with whom I have a problem.

> Show that for any $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M$ and any $q\in \mathbb{Z}$ we have
>
> I) $ \ \ M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(\mathbb{Z}/{q\mathbb{Z}}\right)\cong M/qM$
>
> II) $\ \ \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z},M\right)\cong\left\{ m\in M : \ qm=0\right\}$

I done first part but I don't know how to prove the second part.

Comment: If you look at the map $f \mapsto f(1)$, what do you see?

Comment: $\varphi(f):=f(1)$ is monomorphism. If $m\in\{qm=0\}$ then $\tilde{f}(x):=mx$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ and $M$ and $\tilde{f}(1)=m$, so $\varphi $ is epimorphism. Is it good ?

Comment: You also need to show that the image of $\varphi$ is contained in $\{ m : qm = 0\}$. That's pretty obvious, but nevertheless must be said.

Comment: Right. Since $f(1)\in M$ and $qf(1)=f(q)=f(0)=0$, it is obvious that $f(1)\in\{qm=0\}$. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I) More generally, consider a short exact sequence $0\longrightarrow I\xrightarrow{\ \ \iota\ \ }R\xrightarrow{\ \ \pi\ \ }R/I\longrightarrow 0$. Tensoring with $M$ gives a right exact sequence
$$I\otimes M\xrightarrow{\iota\otimes\operatorname{id}}R\otimes M\xrightarrow{\pi\otimes\operatorname{id}} (R/I)\otimes M\longrightarrow 0\,.$$ Now there is an isomorphism $R\otimes M\xrightarrow{r\otimes m\ \longmapsto\  r\cdot m}M$ with inverse $m\longmapsto 1\otimes m$, hence yielding a right exact sequence
$$I\otimes M\xrightarrow{i\otimes m\ \longmapsto\  i\cdot m}M\xrightarrow{m\ \longmapsto\  \pi(1)\otimes m}(R/I)\otimes M\longrightarrow 0\,.$$
The image of the first arrow is equal to $I\cdot M$, whence $(R/I)\otimes M\cong M/IM$.

II) Again, consider a short exact sequence $0\longrightarrow I\xrightarrow{\ \ \iota\ \ }R\xrightarrow{\ \ \pi\ \ }R/I\longrightarrow 0$. The universal property of the quotient gives an isomorphism
$$\hom(R/I,M)\xrightarrow{\varphi\ \longmapsto\ \varphi\pi}\left\{f\in\hom(R,M)\mid f\iota=0\right\}\,.$$
Now there is an isomorphism
$$\hom(R,M)\xrightarrow{f\ \longmapsto\  f(1)}M\,.$$
 We have $$\begin{align*}f\iota=0&\iff\forall i\in I:fi=0\iff\forall i\in I: f(i\cdot 1)=0\iff\forall i\in I: i\cdot f(1)=0\\&\iff I\cdot f(1)=0\,.\end{align*}$$

Restricting, we find an isomorphism
$$\left\{f\in\hom(R,M)\mid f\iota=0\right\}\xrightarrow{f\ \longmapsto\  f(1)}\left\{m\in M\mid Im=0\right\}\,.$$
Composing, we find $\hom(R/I,M)\cong\left\{m\in M\mid Im=0\right\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be a left ideal of $R$ and $M$ be a right $R$-module. You can consider the commutative diagram with exact rows
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
{} @. M\otimes_R I @>>> M\otimes_R R @>>> M\otimes_R R/I @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VV\varphi V \\
0 @>>> MI @>>> M @>>> M/MI @>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$
where the rightmost vertical arrow is defined by $\varphi(m\otimes(r+I))=m+MI$.

Since the leftmost vertical arrow (defined by $m\otimes r\mapsto mr$) is surjective and the center vertical arrow (defined by $m\otimes r\mapsto mr$) is an isomorphism, the five lemma tells you that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism

Similarly, if $J$ is a right ideal of $R$, you can consider the diagram with exact rows
$$\def\H{\operatorname{Hom}_R}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \H(R/J,M) @>>> \H(R,M) \\
@. @VV\alpha V @VV\beta V \\
0 @>>> \operatorname{Ann}_M(J) @>>> M 
\end{CD}
$$
where $\operatorname{Ann}_M(J)=\{x\in M:xJ=0\}$.

The horizontal maps are the obvious ones, $\alpha(f)=f(1+J)$ and $\beta(g)=g(1)$. Since $\beta$ is clearly an isomorphism, we get that $\alpha$ is injective. Suppose $x\in\operatorname{Ann}_M(J)$; then the kernel of the homomorphism $g\colon r\mapsto xr$ contains $J$, so it factors through $R/J$. This implies $\alpha$ is surjective.